# Where is the Windows 10 PIN stored?

Tags: windows-10, hashing, ntlm

I know that Windows 10 stores passwords in a NTLM hash in a SAM file.

Where is the Windows 10 PIN hash stored?

Answer (score 3):

In Windows 10 and 8 the PIN hashes are located in `C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\LocalService\AppData\Local\Microsoft\NGC` folder.

Answer (score -3):

I recently pulled the CMOS battery of a laptop during a repair, and the Windows 11 PIN reset. So I suspect the CMOS is somehow involved in storing the PIN.

Comment: The Windows pin absolutely is NOT stored in a device's firmware (CMOS). Pulling the battery reset the CMOS configuration for your own security as a precaution; Windows treats that as a security event requiring you to change or update your pin. The action is related but the pin absolutely is NOT stored in the CMOS of a device.