# Is it possible to change a PIN, picture password, and/or security key from a batch file or PowerShell script in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, powershell, batch-file, pin, windows-hello

In a batch file or PowerShell script, is it possible to change a user's PIN, picture password, and/or security key?

**Password:** I am using `net user USERNAME \password:NEWPASSWORD`.
**PIN:** I hear that the pin hashes are stored in `C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\LocalService\AppData\Local\Microsoft\NGC` (from [this](https://superuser.com/a/1414973) answer). However, I am not sure how to edit the hashes, or to add them if a PIN is not already present.
**Picture Password:** There are a lot of locations in which I see the picture password picture. I find the picture in `C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\PicturePassword` and in `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\SystemData\SECURITYIDENTIFIER\ReadOnly\PicturePassword`. I also see quite a few keys in the registry that contain the phrase `PicturePassword`. In mimikatz, I can also find the picture password as a System credential. Which should I update with the location of a new picture password, and where is the combination stored?
**Security Key:** I have no idea where this is stored.

Any ideas?

Comment: You don't edit hashes. Hashes are generated by the system based on DPAPI.

Comment: You can set a local user password in Powershell with `Set-LocalUser`. I believe the other options are not accessible from Powershell at all by design, since those features are typically disabled in enterprise and business environments.

Comment: Oh, an modifying the hashes directly is not going to be useful They're going to be stored with one-way encryption. If you could edit the hash and gain access, then the entire computing world would love to know about it because you'll have broken some pretty major encryption standards doing it.